# How to detect which radio button was clicked in h:selectOneRadio using javascript or rich:jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, richfaces

How to detect which radio button was clicked in h:selectOneRadio using javascript or maybe jquery?

I can already do this using valueChangeListener and a4j:support from managed bean. 
What i want is not to go to the server and just use jquery just for performance, because sometimes 
it takes time before the server response comes back.

What i want is when a radio button was clicked it will disable some of my components.

Here is the code.

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="isPrivate" valueChangeListener="#{someBean.changeRadio}">
                    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="sp" />            
                    <f:selectItem id="isPrivate0" itemLabel="No" itemValue="false"/>
                    <f:selectItem id="isPrivate1" itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true"/>         
                </h:selectOneRadio>
```

Thanks in advanced.
:)

Comment: "*What i want is when a radio button was clicked it will disable some of my components.*" - I hope that you're well aware that since you want to disable them in the client side only (and not in the server (JSF) side), a hacker could still easily submit values to those components by just tampering the request.

Comment: thank you for your reply. i guess i'll stick with my current implementation. ^^,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd better attach change event to each radio button in the list on document's onload.

```
$(function()
{
    $('table[id$="isPrivate"] input:radio',this).each(function (){ 
                $(this).change(function (event) { 

                //do disabling here
                //$(this).val() - will return the value of radiobutton
                });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery:

```
jQuery('input[name=isPrivate]:checked').val()
```

example:

```
if (jQuery('input[name=isPrivate]:checked').val() == "true") {
    //yes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to find the `<input type='radio' …/>` elements JSF generates, and listen to the *change* event using, say, jQuery's [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).